# what is the difference between producer and regular actor?

Tags: akka, actor, producer

akka doc (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/camel.html) shows that camel procedure is an actor:

```
class Orders extends Actor with Producer with Oneway {
    def endpointUri = "jms:queue:Orders"
}

val sys = ActorSystem("some-system")
val orders = sys.actorOf(Props[Orders])
```

what are the differences between a camel producer and a regular actor, for example,
does producer has mailbox and dispatcher, which i can set in my code?

Answer (score 0):

A Producer is just a regular Actor with mailbox and dispatcher but with a predefined behavior of sending the messages it receives to the Endpoint that it is configured with.